# wordpress site still points to old host after dns changed

Tags: php, wordpress, dns

Hope you are enjoying your Sunday!  Quick Question I hope, I'm in the process of moving a wordpress site from one host to another (domain name will stay the same).

So far, I've ftp'ed all of the directories, files, etc. to the new host, email is up and functional, changed the wordpress entries to point to the new database and user id, and was able to access the wordpress site on the new host.  So far, so good...

Yesterday, I changed the DNS record to point to the new host servers and the InterNic record reflects this.  However, when I attempt to go to the site, its still pointed to the old host.

So, with that, is this a simple matter of timing or is there an entry somewhere in wordpress that has the ip address and/or dns servers of the old host hard coded that I should be looking for to change?

Thanks for your insight and support!
Rita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, you do get strange events happening for up to 2-3 days after a DNS change.

There is nothing to change within the Wordpress core. There is always a possibility that a plugin may store the IP but that should not stop you accessing your site.

You could try flushing the DNS on your PC. From the command prompt (assuming windows) type **ipconfig /flushdns**  Depending on your Windows version, this may need elevated privileges.

Comment: Thanks MortimerCat!  That was the trick. All seems to be up and ok.  Take Care! :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just need to wait for your DNS changes [to propagate](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/dns-propagation-and-caching/).

You could also [modify your network settings](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) to use a different DNS server (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are Google's public DNS servers), which in most cases will let you access your new host (ip) via your domain.